# simple_form and custom validation message

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

**Intro:**
Using `simple_form` in app, added validations to attributes and errors display properly next to each field in form. Also I have 2 custom validation that adds custom error messages not related to attributes of the model.

**The problem:**
In a basic rails form the errors are displayed above the form and also the ones from custom validation appears. But how can I show custom validation messages using `simple_form`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use a [form object](https://github.com/apotonick/reform) where you don't need to save errors in the `base` of the object. You would just create new attributes with those validations and add it to the view which would work out of the box with `simple_form`.

Comment: Well, I don't see how can I relate my validations to attributes of any kind. What I check in my custom validation is - if User or Invitation with this email exists when someone invites a user through UserInvitation it should display these errors. So I am not sure I can relate this scenario to attributes. User and UserInvitation are 2 different models. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this so far:

```
  <% if @object.errors.messages[:base].present? %>
    <ul class="error_messages_container">
    <% @object.errors.messages[:base].each do |e| %>
      <li><%= e %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

that I placed above the form, so I'll have my custom validation messages above the form.
Also, waiting for other ideas.